# MVC Web Api Get Data with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get all my posts from the database to be displayed with the help of ajax or getjson but can't get it to work. Using mvc web api and I have a view where I want to display it.  There is a method working called post so nothing wrong with my routing etc.

Code for my views js-script, I want to display all posts with the help of my mvc api controller and ajax in a div called #userMessage.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btnGetPosts').click(function() {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        var recieverID = $('#RecieverID').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Posts/GetPosts" ,
            //data: (?)
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            error: function(request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

my controller method to get all the posts

```
     //   GET: api/Posts
        public IEnumerable<Post> GetPosts()
        {

 //querystring is made to get the recieverID, it's also reachable in the view.      //("#RecieverID")
            string querystring = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Username"];



            // Converts Username querystring to a user-id
            int id = UserRepository.GetUserId(querystring);

            // uses linq to get a specific user post (all posts)
            var userPost = PostRepository.GetSpecificUserPosts(id);

            return userPost;
        }
```

my PostRepository.GetSpecifiedUserPosts method in my repository

```
  public List<Post> GetSpecificUserPosts(int user)
    {
        using (var context = new DejtingEntities())
        {
            var result = context.Posts
                .Where(x => x.RecieverID == user)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)


                .ToList();

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: What happens? Is your `$.ajax` `error` handler invoked? If so, what is the `statusCode` from the server, and what is the `responseText` (if any)? Also, it looks like you are using WebAPI, not MVC (they are different). If you are using an `ApiController`, you should remove your MVC tag and its mentions in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#btnGetPosts').click(function() {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        var recieverID = $('#RecieverID').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Posts/Posts" ,
            data: {
              username: recieverID 
            },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            error: function(request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and in code behind,

```
public IEnumerable<Post> GetPosts(string username)
{   
    // Converts Username querystring to a user-id
    int id = UserRepository.GetUserId(username);

    // uses linq to get a specific user post (all posts)
    var userPost = PostRepository.GetSpecificUserPosts(id);

    return userPost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong url. Try send ajax request to `'/api/Posts'`.

Also you can add routing attribute to the action `[Route('/api/Posts/GetPosts')]` and send request to `'/api/Posts/GetPosts'`.

See [Calling the Web API with Javascript and jQuery](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) and [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api).